# DNS Failover between 2 Data Centers

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

Scenario is this :

In a simplified deployment scenario, need to specify a single IP address of NAV Application Server for various POS machines to communicate with it. In this particular scenario of two Data Centres, with multiple Servers for each role (e.g., two NAV Application Servers in active-passive mode in each DC, two SQL Servers in active-passive mode in each DC, eight DD Servers in each DC, one Reporting Server in each DC, etc.), how do we overcome the requirement of specifying the single IP address? Can it be done through DNS resolution process? If yes, how?

What exactly cient wants-

Client wants 1 active and 1 passive dns both at 2 separate data centers. He wants if either one of dns server pair failes, other can take over the network for name resolution.

Comment: Why active-passive? It's DNS. They can all be active.

Comment: he want's to have it like this and also wants if DC1's active dns goes down, passive should take over the network and when this one goes down then DC2's active DNS should take over the whole network.
can this be possible ?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can accomplish this by deploying two dns server each on in each data center and connect them with high availability connecting two dns servers to HA (high availability)heart beat  connecting two dns servers if active server goes down heart beat message stop travelingin in HA cable passive server stop listening heart beat messages and passive dns will failover to active taking work load . But at top level domain server we need to request to point towards failover dns when failover occurs.

Comment: Can you guide me with the steps, I've never done it before.

Comment: Which dns are you using I mean window DNS or any third-party vendor example "inflobox"

Comment: I'm using Windows Server DNS and I don't need to go over WAN.